# Find duplicate items in csv file

Tags: c#, csv

I have a CSV file  with

> FirstName LastName and ID column, Id is an Unique Column

```
Chris, Webber, 1 
Chris, Ben, 2
Chris, Dudley, 3
David, Floy, 4
Chris, Ben, 5 
Chris, Webber, 6
```

I need to get two list without using a DB, i need to read it from file in c# and create two list duplicate list and originalList.

duplicate list has all the duplicates  entry

```
Chris, Webber, 1
Chris, Webber, 6
Chris, Ben, 2
Chris, Ben, 5
```

Original List has unique entry and first occurrence of duplicate entry.

```
Chris, Webber, 1
Chris, Ben, 2
Chris, Dudley, 3
David, Floy, 4
```

> What is the best way solve this?

Comment: So which part are you struggling with, reading the data into a list or extracting the data into two lists?

Comment: i was struggling with best solution based on performance

Answer (score 6):

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("yourFile.ext");

// this assumes you can hold the whole file in memory

// uniqueness is defined by the first two columns
var grouped = lines.GroupBy(line => string.Join(", ", line.Split(',').Take(2)))
                   .ToArray();

// "unique entry and first occurrence of duplicate entry" -> first entry in group
var unique = grouped.Select(g => g.First());

var dupes = grouped.Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                   .SelectMany(g => g);

Console.WriteLine("unique");
foreach (var name in unique)
    Console.WriteLine(name);

Console.WriteLine("\nDupes");
foreach (var name in dupes)
    Console.WriteLine(name);
```

Output:

```
unique
Chris, Webber, 1
Chris, Ben, 2
Chris, Dudley, 3
David, Floy, 4

Dupes
Chris, Webber, 1
Chris, Webber, 6
Chris, Ben, 2
Chris, Ben, 5
```

Comment: oh phooy, do all his work for him.  Like the answer though, never occurred to me to use grouping on the split

Answer (score 1):

read it in line by line, treat like a plain text file.

parse each line using `string.split` on ','

use one `List` to track ID's, using .Contains

use custom data object structures for the data itself, and make two lists, one for the unique entries and one for the duplicates. (total of 3 lists)

if you want actual code examples, please give a list of things you have tried for me to debug along with what the errors are.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a String Array/Map/ArrayList/List that will hold the unique ID's. --- Use whichever you are most comofrtable working with.
2. Read the file in line by line
3. Check if ID is already part of Array/Map/ArrayList/List you created - if it is not, add it to the array list, if it is then do not.

As you are adding it to the array list you can also add the entire row in to a dataset which you can use to store all the unique records that you now have.